# Can't process workflow emails in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a sharepoint system with a separate exchange server. We can send emails through the exchange server from one user to another. when we try to start a workflow, users can be validated within the Active Directory. However, the email notifications are not being processed. The workflow errors out saying "cannot send email".
I need this running tonight
Any ideas? There is something I have forgotten to do in SP Central Admin and I can't remember what it is.  HELP

Answer (score 0):

Configure in SP Central Admin under System Settings -> E-Mail and Text Messages (SMS) 
-> Configure outgoing e-mail settings